# How to copy files from ec2 instance of Account A to s3 bucket of Account B in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have few files in an ec2 machine of Account A. I would like to copy these files to a s3 bucket in Account B with User A( belongs to Account A). Could you please guide me with the necessary IAM policy or the list of procedures to be followed to achieve this?

Comment: Does "User A" belong to Account A or Account B?

Comment: User A belongs to Account A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy files from an Amazon EC2 instance in Account-A to an S3 Bucket (`Bucket-B`) in Account-B, you would:

- Create an **IAM Role** (`Role-A`) and assign it to the EC2 instance in Account-A
- In `Role-A`, grant permission to use `Bucket-B` (see below)
- Add a **Bucket Policy** to `Bucket-B` that grants permission (see below) for `Role-A`

Since you are using `aws s3 sync`, you will need to grant permission to List and Put objects:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that you need **two** sets of permissions:

- One on the IAM Role assigned to the EC2 instance (`Role-A`)
- One on the Bucket Policy in Account-B (`Bucket-B`)

These policies are slightly different because the Bucket Policy will need the `Principal` to refer to the ARN of `Role-A` whereas the IAM policy for Role-A (shown above) does not require a `Principal` to be defined.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks much, John. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

1.Check if you have IAM roles or policies which will allow the required process if not set up required  rules to allow cross-account access.

2.check if the AWS CLI is installed on EC2 instance, if not install it.

3.then configure the AWS CLI with the help of "aws configure"

4.after configuring you can use command "aws s3 cp /path/to/local/file s3:///path/to/s3/

Answer (score -2):

1. Create an IAM policy in account A with Full S3 access and generate the programmatic access keys
2. SSH to ec2 in account B, and [install AWS-CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html#getting-started-install-instructions)
3. Create a credentials file ~/.aws/credentials

```
[accounta]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_HERE
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE
```

3. Create a config file ~/.aws/config

```
[accounta]
region = xx-xxxxx-n
output = table
```

4. Run the following command to copy all the files to S3 bucket
   `aws --profile accounta s3 sync ./source/ s3://target-bucket/`

Comment: Hardcoding credentials on an EC2 instance is almost never a good idea

Comment: Can't store credentials of account A in Account B. That will violate our security. Need a cross object reference policy.

Comment: Ok. you did not mention the security constraint in your quesion. The approach provided still works as expected.